# Is the diagonal of finitely presented groups computable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic

Let $f:G\to H$ be a surjective homomorphism of finitely presented groups. If the kernel of $f$ is finitely generated then is $G\times_H G$ is a finitely presented group? Can one compute an explicit finite presentation?

Comment: If $F$ is free of finite rank and $Q$ is an infinite quotient of $F$ with infinite kernel, then the fiber product $F\times_Q F$ is not finitely presentable.

Comment: @YCor I edited is it correct now?

Comment: I haven't checked whether your condition now implies finite presentability. But what is the input then? Just asking whether the kernel is finitely generated is not algorithmically solvable in general.

Comment: added generators of the kernel to the input

Comment: If you checked that the fiber product is finitely presentable, don't you get an explicit finite presentation?

Comment: @YCor: the fact that they are finitely presented follows from the 1-2-3 theorem of Baumslag--Bridson--Miller--Short, but the proof doesn't give an explicit presentation.

Comment: @YCor: I omitted to mention that there is an extra hypthesis needed, namely that the quotient $H$ should be of type $F_3$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is "no".  The hypotheses for the fibre product to be finitely presentable are given by the 1-2-3 theorem of Bridson--Baumslag--Miller--Short:

> **1-2-3 Theorem (BBMS):** The fibre product $G\times_H G$ is guaranteed to be finitely presentable as long as:
>
> 1. the kernel of $G\to H$ is finitely generated;
> 2. $G$ itself is finitely presented;
> 3. $H$ satisfies a higher finiteness condition, namely being of "type $F_3$".

However, there is no general algorithm that can compute a finite presentation for $G\times_H G$. Indeed, stronger, there is no algorithm that can compute its abelianisation, and the result follows since the abelianisation can be computed from a finite presentation.

This is proved in my paper with Bridson:

> Bridson & Wilton, "On the difficulty of presenting finitely presentable groups", *Groups Geom. Dyn.* 5(2), pp. 301–325, 2011

available on the arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5117). See Theorem A, and note in the proof that the subgroup $\Lambda_n$ is indeed a fibre product.

To give a brief sketch of the argument, one takes a sequence of perfect groups $Q_n$ such that the second Betti numbers $b_2(Q_n)$ are known to be impossible to compute. The Rips short exact sequence gives

$$1\to K_n\to\Gamma_n\to Q_n\to 1$$

with $K_n$ finitely generated, and then let $\Lambda_n\leq \Gamma_n\times\Gamma_n$ be the fibre product. Finally, an argument with the Stallings exact sequence relates the Betti numbers:

$$b_1(\Lambda_n) = 2b_1(\Gamma_n)+b_2(Q_n).$$

Since $b_1(\Gamma_n)$ is computabe and $b_2(Q_n)$ isn't, it follows that $b_1(\Lambda_n)$ is not computable. In particular, no presentation for $\Lambda_n$ can be computed, even though we are given explicit generating sets and know that they are finitely presented.

Comment: So then at which level in the arithmetical hiearchy is the claim that a given group is finitely presentable? Seems like an oracle for the halting problem couldn't solve that?

Comment: @Oniqa: that question is above my pay-grade, unfortunately!

Comment: @Oniqa What data are you using to represent the group? Are we talking about arbitrary computable groups? Or do you mean relative to the group as an oracle?

Comment: @Oniqa I guess it doesn't really matter that much. Suppose you're given a group as an oracle $G$. If you pick some finite set $\bar{a}$ of elements and some relations on those, checking to see if those relations give a presentation of the subgroup generated by $\bar{a}$ is a $\Pi^0_1(G)$ condition.

Comment: @Oniqa To see this, note that checking to see that the subgroup satisfies the generators is $\Delta^0_0(G)$, but checking to see that the subgroup *only* satisfies those generators is $\Pi^0_1(G)$ (for any pair of words in $\bar{a}$ whose products in $G$ are not equal, there is no derivation from the generators that implies they must be equal).

Comment: @Oniqa Checking to see if the subgroup generated by the $\bar{a}$ is the whole group is a $\Pi^0_2(G)$ condition (for every element of the group, there exists a product...), so checking to see if a given choice of presentation is in fact a presentation is $\Pi^0_2(G)$.

Comment: @Oniqa Checking to see if a finite presentation exists is therefore $\Sigma^0_3(G)$, which implies that checking to see if no such finite presentation exists is $\Pi^0_3(G)$. So all told, deciding if a given group has a finite presentation takes at most $3$ Turing jumps above the complexity of the group itself. I don't know if this is optimal, but usually these kinds of things aren't any easier than a naïve calculation like this. (Although I also may have miscounted.)